# Python @dataclasses - how to properly measure size of classes with pympler.asizeof?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I was testing some python @dataclasses and I have met something new.

I was using pympler.asizeof to measure my classes size and I have found some problem.
Why the order of elements in asizeof function matters?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from pympler import asizeof

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class TEST1():
    __slots__ = ['id', 'value']
    id: int
    value: float

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class TEST2():
    id: int
    value: float

test_1 = TEST1(1, 2)
test_2 = TEST2(1,2)

a = 1
b = 2

print(asizeof.asizesof(test_1, test_2))
print(asizeof.asizesof(test_2, test_1))

print(asizeof.asizesof(a, test_1, test_2))
print(asizeof.asizesof(a, test_2, test_1))

print(asizeof.asizesof(a, a, test_1, test_2))
print(asizeof.asizesof(a, a, test_2, test_1))

print(asizeof.asizesof(a, b, test_1, test_2))
print(asizeof.asizesof(a, b, test_2, test_1))
```

Results:

```
(112, 264)
(328, 48)
(32, 80, 264)
(32, 296, 48)
(32, 32, 80, 264)
(32, 32, 296, 48)
(32, 32, 48, 264)
(32, 32, 264, 48)
```

Comment: i think for class instance you should use `ClassTracker` to get more view